# PyQt6-Charts: Donut Chart (aka circle graph) crashes on animation

Tags: python, pyqt6

This is my minimum reproducible example of a donut chart (aka circle graph)

I am trying to animate it but my code crashes on line 24 with error:

**chart.setAnimationOptions(chart.SeriesAnimations)
AttributeError: 'QChart' object has no attribute 'SeriesAnimations'**

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QPieSeries
from PyQt6.QtGui import QPainter
from PyQt6.QtCore import Qt

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setWindowTitle("Temperature Chart Example")
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        series = QPieSeries()
        # Current temperature
        series.append("Current Temperature", 30)
        # Remaining temperature
        series.append("Remaining Temperature", 70)

        # Set the hole size
        series.setHoleSize(0.6)

        chart = QChart()
        chart.addSeries(series)
        chart.setTitle("Current Temperature")
        chart.setAnimationOptions(chart.SeriesAnimations)

        chart.legend().setVisible(True)

        chart_view = QChartView(chart)
        chart_view.setRenderHint(QPainter.RenderHint.Antialiasing)

        # Create a layout to hold both the chart and the label
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(chart_view)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)

        # Create a central widget to hold the layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)

        # Set the widget as the central widget of the window
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)


app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
window.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: I have edited the code above to reflect @Issylin answer. It is now a working example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SeriesAnimations` is an enum value from [QChart](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/PySide6/QtCharts/QChart.html). What matters here is that it is located within `AnimationOption`.

In order to use the values of this enum, you have to explicitly indicate where it comes from. Consequently, your line must either change to :

`chart.setAnimationOptions(chart.AnimationOption.SeriesAnimations)`

or

`chart.setAnimationOptions(QChart.AnimationOption.SeriesAnimations)`

Comment: Side note, it goes the same way for all the other enums from QChart. Let's say you'd like to use `QChart.ChartThemeLight`, you cannot directly use it as `chart.ChartThemeLight`. Instead, it would have been `chart.ChartTheme.ChartThemeLight` or `myVar = QChart.ChartTheme.ChartThemeLight`

Comment: Actually, it goes the same way for **all** Qt enums since PyQt6. And it will become mandatory for PySide6 too in the near future.